# ¿Como puedo poner un background de imagen para cada pagina php sin usar dos archivos css?

Tags: php, css, html5

Tengo dos paginas php con diferentes background pero usos dos archivos css, como puedo poner un background para cada pagina sin usar dos archivos css

Comment: Bienvenido @Nicolás Ramos Díaz a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas. Asimismo es recomendable que se sigan las directrices contenidas en [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para que la comunidad pueda ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 1):

Sí, claro, puedes llamar al mismo .css desde dos .php diferentes. Simplemente tienes que definir una clase diferente para cada uno:

styles.css

```
body.fondo1{
    background-color: yellow;
}

body.fondo2{
    background-color: gray;
}
```

php1.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body class="fondo1">
    Hola Mundo
</body>
</html>
```

php2.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body class="fondo2">
    Hola Mundo
</body>
</html>
```

Espero haberte ayudado, el CSS es bastante lioso. Inténtalo tú y, la próxima vez, envíanos las pruebas que has hecho más o menos así. De esta forma nos resultará muy fácil corregir lo que no esté funcionando.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda. funciono perfectamente.